# Find WordChain of a fixed length Java

Tags: java, dictionary, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

First of all the Word Chain problem for those who are unfamiliar is; when given a dictionary of words, find a path from one word to another using only one letter changes. eg.

Given Dictionary  `[dog, dot, cot, cat, cut, cab]`
Make a path from dog to cat changing one letter at a time. Path would be `dog > dot > cot > cat`

Usually with Word Chains you would want to find the shortest path from dog -> cat using BFS, but how would you go about making a path of a fixed length e.g you are given input `dog cat 5` which wants you to get from dog to cat in 5 steps.

The new path would be `dog > dot > cot > cut > cat` and using normal BFS to find the shortest path would no longer work.

This is my current code that takes in a dictionary, stores it and computes each words "adjacent words" (one letter changes) that are in the dictionary.

```
private static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> adjacentWords = new HashMap<>();
private static HashSet<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();

private static void initDictionary() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      String word = input.nextLine();
      dictionary.add(word);
      adjacentWords.put(word, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    input.close();
/** Checks each word in the dictionary one letter changes, if the word exists in dictionary, 
  * add it as an adjacent word
*/

    for(String word: adjacentWords.keySet()){
      
      for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
        char[] words = word.toCharArray();
        for(char c = 'a'; c<= 'z'; c++){
          words[i]= c;
          String oneLetterChange = String.valueOf(keys);
          if(dictionary.contains(oneLetterChange)){
            adjacentWords.get(words).add(oneLetterChange);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Assumption

1. A vertex should be visited only once

#### Brute Force - Top down recursion

Lets us define few variables:

1. `pathLength` be the number of edges required in the expected path from source to target (if such path exists)
2. `graph` be an adjacency representation
3. `count` be the number of vertices. each vertex in the graph have an id in range [0, count)

The algorithm could be a method that takes parameters

1. graph
2. count
3. current (vertex id at present)
4. to (target vertex id)
5. pathLength (remaining path length)
6. path (structure to hold current path)

The method can check the exit conditions

1. `pathLength < 0` is an invalid state in a forward only state machine and hence will return `null`
2. `pathLength == 0` and `current == to`, then we found a path, so return `path`
3. `pathLength == 0` and `current != to`, then return `null`
4. `pathLength > 0 and` current == to`, then return` null`

The actual calls will be

1. iterate over all the unvisited edges from `current`
2. mark `to` as visited
3. add `to` to path
4. invoke the method with `edge.to` and `pathLength - 1`
5. if a path was found, (non-null response), then return path
6. if null response, then backtrack (mark to as `unvisited` and pop `to` from path)

Sample code with `Integer` to represent vertex

```java
protected List<Integer> findPathWithLength(final int source, final int to, 
    final int pathLength, List<List<Integer>> graph, boolean[] visited, 
    List<Integer> path) {

    if (pathLength == 0 && source == to) {
        return path;
    } 
    if (pathLength < 0 || (pathLength == 0 && source != to)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int adj : graph.getDirectlyConnectedVertices(current)) {
        if (visited[adj]) {
            continue;
        }
        visited[adj] = true;
        path.add(adj);
        List<Integer> result = findPathWithLength(adj, to, pathLength - 1, 
            graph, visited, path);
        if (result != null) {
            return result; // result and path are same in this code
        }
        visited[adj] = false;
        path.remove(path.length - 1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

#### memoization using vertex pairs and pathLength

1. for each pair of vertices, try to find the edges with length in range [0, pathLength] and memoize this result
2. finally return cachce[start][end][pathLength]